# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_xml' or 'to_xml'

Tags: pandas, xml, xml-parsing, opml

Im trying to parse feedly RSS feeds exported opml files into xml files.

I succeeded into doing so with my use of listparser, dicttoxml, and pandas. I wanted to try out pandas read_xml() and to_xml() to find out how it would perform compared to me parsing the opml to xml myself.

```
import pandas as pd
my_opml = './feedly-e42affb2-52f5-4889-8901-992e3a3e35de-2021-06-28.opml'
df = pd.read_xml(my_opml)
```

these would be the error that i get.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/home/pysolver33/anaconda3/envs/feedly/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5465, in **getattr**
> return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_xml'

```
df.to_xml("feedlyRSS.xml")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/home/pysolver33/anaconda3/envs/feedly/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 244, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_xml'

My pandas version is 1.2.5. I checked pip and 1.2.5 should be the latest version. Is there a particular reason why i can't play with read_xml or to_xml?

Comment: `read_xml` will be available only in version 1.3, which hasn't been released yet.

Comment: i see! thank you for telling me about it. i was reading both from the official documents and was confused why i can't use them. again thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update `pandas` to the newest version.

`pip install --upgrade pandas --user`

`pd.read_xml('file.xml')` is available in version 1.3.0.

Comment: My pandas is v1.3.3 but still got the error

Comment: It works on `1.4.4` and `1.5.2`.