# Pandas read_xml - AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_xml'

Tags: python, pandas, xml, readxml

I ran into the error:

" AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_xml' "

This would be a huge lifesaver if I could ingest the XML with one function into a pandas df without trying to iterate through etc.

I am running pandas 1.3.4 and python 3.8.8.  I have tried opening an xml in my local folder (where the script is housed).

I tried directly importing the file like so:

`df = pd.read_xml('xmltest.xml')`

As well as trying to import via a string like so:

`txt = Path('xmltest.txt').read_text()`

`df = pd.read_xml(txt)`

And both gave me the wrong error..  Any help would be awesome as this would be AMAZING to ingest XML with 1 function into a DF!!!  Are there similar functions out there if this is no longer a valid solution?

It appears this person had the same problem but I'm currently running the updated pandas:

[AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_xml' or 'to_xml'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166626/attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-read-xml-or-to-xml/72748941?noredirect=1#comment128497931_72748941)

Comment: Check if you really use pandas >= 1.3.0. `import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: oh wow, it says 1.2.4..!  (in anaconda).  when I did pip show pandas in cmd, it said the other one above..  Going to try now

Comment: @Corralien it worked!  Now to figure out why it's not parsing properly..

Comment: Glad to help you :)